# How to do multi column sorting in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to do sorting on multiple columns, means based on first column data second column need to be sorted and based on second column data third column need to be sorted. like this I have to sort. Please suggest me how to implement this using angular component level or typescript base.

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm plugin Its have the feature to sort multiple columns
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-multi-sort

Comment: The link is an incomplete answer, since the resource may be deleted. Please complete the answer with an example of usage.